# Space complexity of an array

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I recently came across a problem that made me wonder.
What if I stored a N element array inside an array of length N across all the N indexes.
As a tiny example:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10],
]
```

*An array of length 3 and at every index there is an array again of length 3*

What would be the space complexity? Is it still O(N) or has it change.

Answer (score 0):

It would still be `O(n)` because the Space Complexity analysis is meant to describe the complexity of the relationship between n and space, it doesn't care if you store an array of 3 elements at every index. The space used will be 3 times higher but still the relationship will be linear.

> Big-O notation describes an asymptotic upper bound. It represents the
> algorithm’s scalability and performance.
>
> Simply put, it gives the worst-case scenario of an algorithm’s growth
> rate.

from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/space-complexity).

It would be different if you said that at every index an array of `N=index` elements is stored. In that case it would have been `O(n^2)`.